# Composer not installed correctly missing "vendor/bin" file?

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I'm having a problem when I install Composer on my Windows 10 I can't find the folder "vendor" C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Composer. So I can't set a path in my "Environment Variables" in windows system.

I already installed Composer many times.

So, when I'm trying to create a new folder using a laravel command "laravel new laratest" I get an error "'laravel' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." I really hope I can get a solution here so I can continue with my laravel project.

Comment: Have you tried using `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog` instead so you won't have to install the laravel installer globally?

Answer (score 3):

The environment variable problem, because of your composer is not in environment globally. 
you may follow these steps:

> Don't worry about the path, It may vary.

May be it will be `C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin` instead of `C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Composer`

And for the second one, you must install laravel installer first. run the code below

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8 look the installer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply !  I already found this folder C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin but when i try to run this command "composer global require laravel/installer" I get  this error message "Changed current directory to C:/Users/fikri/AppData/Roaming/Composer


  [ErrorException]
  file_put_contents(C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Composer): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: If you dont mind, i will tell you to remove composer from control panel. then reinstall it with the php.exe path selected.

Comment: I tried reinstalling it and restart my laptop still I get the same error message. I tried to give access to my ./composer folder but same error message.